# Is there a way to add WCF svc-less activation with multiple service Activations?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, svc

Given the following configuration:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
    <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="./UserService.svc" service="Mercato.KnowledgeKube.WebSvc.Service.KnowledgeuserManagerService" factory="Mercato.KnowledgeKube.WebSvc.WCF.KnowledgeServiceHostFactory" />
        <add relativeAddress="./ProductService.svc" service="Mercato.KnowledgeKube.WebSvc.Service.ProductManagerWebServices" factory="Mercato.KnowledgeKube.WebSvc.WCF.KnowledgeServiceHostFactory" />
   </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

The first of the two ./UserService is reachable and I can create a Service Reference to it, but the ProductServce is not reconcilable.  What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

here is the Exception:

```
 There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/KnowledgeWebService/ProductService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution   
and adding the service reference again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't an endpoint listening because......I hadn't decorared the product service with the relevant attributes.  I was looking for more complex problems first.