# WCF Service - service in separate class library

Tags: c#, wcf

This is my project diagram:

- MyWCFService

  - (...)
  - web.config
- Friends.Implementation

  - Friends.svc

    - Friends.svc.cs
- Friends.Contract

  - IFriends.cs

My endpoint of service:

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Friends.Implementation.Friends">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Friends.Contract.IFriends" />
  </service>
```

My question is: How can I call this service? When I had that service in "Service" folder in MyWCFService project, it was easy - just `localhost:XX/Services/Friends.svc`.

And now, how can I run it, if everything is in separate class libraries?

Regards

Comment: Why you have Friends separated ?

Comment: What type of project is Friends.Implementation?

Comment: @kostas so you can reuse the data contracts in the client application without having to refer to the service implementation.

Comment: @CodeCaster You r right, i haven't thought like that cause usually i use data contracts only for service purpose. Thx for your mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Services` folder in your website root and paste the `.svc` file there, or you can use [service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816902(v=vs.110).aspx) [activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343364/is-there-a-way-to-add-wcf-svc-less-activation-with-multiple-service-activations):

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="Friends.Implementation.Friends" 
             relativeAddress="Services/Friends.svc"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `relativeAddress` is requied for `add` - what should I type here?

Comment: @whoah see edit. See [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for some explanation on activation.